# Mathematical operation input as a string in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a definition inside a class that should be taking as an input a date separated by "/". However, Python automatically resolves the date as a mathematical operation (ex: 26/05/2015 = 0). The code I've come up with so far is:

```
Ano={1:31,2:28,3:31,4:30,5:31,6:30,7:31,8:31,9:30,10:31,11:30,12:31}

class Date:
    def __init__(self,day,month,year):
        self.day=day
        self.month=month
        self.year=year
        if year%4==0 and year%100!=0:
            if year%400==0:
                Ano[2]=29
    def parse(self,datestring):
        M={'Jan':1,'Feb':2,'Mar':3,'Apr':4,'May':5,'Jun':6,'Jul':7,'Aug':8,'Sep':9,'Oct':10,'Nov':11,'Dec':12}
        L=datestring.split('/')
        if L[1] in M:
            L[1]=M[L[1]]
        return L
```

It always ends up in an error, as the resulting int has no function split().

Thanks in advance

The datestring is supposed to be the input and I'm having this problem in the parse function.

Comment: Where does `datestring` come from? The issue is probably with the manner in which you collect input, i.e. the difference between `input()` and `raw_input()` What version of python are you using?

Comment: Why show a lot of code that presumably works but not show the code where the problem is?

Comment: Where is datestring coming from?  I assume the problem isn't in the code shown here.

Comment: Try using `"26/05/2015"` instead of `26/05/2015`.

Comment: While we understand the error is raised in the parse function this happens because you passed it a number, not a string. Your problem is in the code that provides the input.

Comment: Kevin, I have already tried that, but I was hoping to have a method that didn't involve introducing it as a string

Comment: @José Strings should be strings...

Comment: Brian, the datestring is supposed to be the argument for that function and I wanted to convert it to a string before python assumes its a division. I'm working with Python 2.7.9

Comment: I see... thanks anyway, I was trying to find a way to simplify the argument input but to no avail

Answer (score 0):

In python the type of a variable can change during the execution of the script.

There can be two scenarios:-

A. Calling your method parse as parse(26/05/2015) will make the data type detestring as int. And this is the cause of the error message your are getting. You can check it by print(type(detesting))

B. The solution of your problem is to convert the variable to string and then calling your parse method. Like, parse(str(26/05/2015))